# Visual Studio 2013 express for web issues

Tags: azure, web, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web and I seem to have run into some problems. 
I have created my sql database in Azure and I am trying to create a website for it using VS. I am following this tutorial:

http://joaoeduardosousa.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/asp-net-mvc-5-connect-with-azure-sqlserver-database/

The problem i am having is step 4 of the tutorial. When I try to create a data model, my options are different to his. In my picture which i cant put up till i reach 10rep points has 4 options nothing relating to the tutorial I am using.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something. I downloaded all the sdks and everything.

All I am trying to do is connect the DB to the website I have created. I have the DB online just wont allow me to connect to it and I have signed in and ready to publish to it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you say what the options are?

Comment: Here are the four options I get when I go through step 4 in the tutorial
(1) EF designer from database
(2) Empty EF Designer model
(3) Empty code first model
(4) Code First from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want option 2 I haven't tried this to be certain but from the description I think option one gives you a database first designer experience - import tables from database onto a designer surface. Option 2 will give you an empty designer which you connect to the database and then define entities in. ( this is what your tutorial does in the next step) option 3 just gives you the basic code first experience - build poco classes by hand and add them into your dbcontext. Option four is going to reverse engineer a db a generate a load of poco classes and a dbcontext.

That would be my guess at least - option 2